# How do you find the length of a window that you ran in Java

Tags: java

I know that .getWidth() gets the width of a window, but what do you need to import in order to use getLength? (In java)

Comment: And what is the length of a window?

Comment: How is length not the same as width?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to JFrame, I believe what you are looking for is `getHeight()`.